# How to remove Facebook tracking from default React Expo project?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, facebook-javascript-sdk, tracker

I created a very basic React Expo application and compiled it to an Android APK. In the Google Play Store I stated that my application does not collect any user data. To be save I installed the APK on my Android device and searched for trackers with [TrackerControl](https://trackercontrol.org/). I was shocked to see that the App is sending data to Amazon and Facebook, although I am 100% sure that I did not implement this!

Is there a way to get rid of this dammit sniffing? I can't put in all the effort to reimplement everything in another framework...

*Update*:
Let me give a reproducible tutorial. First I created a simple expo navite application in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with

```
expo init my-app
cd my-app
```

Then I build the APK with

```
expo build:android -t apk
```

This will print a web link to the console from where I can download the APK after about one hour. I Download it directly with my Android Phone and install it. Then I check which Tracker control and it recognized a lot of tracker software!

[image]

Translated to English: "Recognized tracker libraries:

- Amplitude
- Facebook Ads
- Facebook Analytics
- Facebook Login
- Facebook Share
- Google AdMob
- Google Analytics
- Google Firebase Analytics
- Google Firebase Analytics
- Google Play Install Referrer
- Segment
  "

And it immediately starts sending data to Amazon.com and Facebook.com:

[image]

It shows writes that sending data to Amazon.com is necessary (which it is not!) and the social tracker for Facebook which I also never installed! How can I remove all these trackers and at what point are they added? Maybe during the build process? Because it builds on some server where I lose control about the build process.

Comment: Can you assert, that you did not agree to the inclusion of these trackers when using Expo? Perhaps you may not remove them. Or perhaps it is the [IDE/editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49159) which injects them?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of these libs, you could switch to EAS Build (free tier with some limits like 30 lower prio builds/month, ...). We regarded this rather acceptable and I can confirm, that there are no trackers left using that approach:
[image]